# Python - index 0 is out of bounds pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a problem reading data from Excel. For some reason, it throws me with a message like below. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```py
with open(bb, "r") as p:
    content = p.read()
    p.close()
    file = []
    name1 = str(os.path.basename(bb).rsplit("_", 1)[0])
    file.append(name1)
    dd = pd.DataFrame(file)
    df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/PK.xlsx")
    c = pd.merge(df, dd, left_on="TABNAME", right_on=0)
    d = c.loc[:, "QUERY"]
    e = c.loc[:, "TYPE_PK"]
    f = c.loc[:, "QUERY1"]
    g = c.loc[:, "SCHEMA"]

    if e[0] == "INT":
        content_new1 = re.sub("[\r\n]+", ",", content, flags=re.M)
        content_new2 = re.sub("$", ")", content_new1, flags=re.M)
        content_new3 = re.sub("^", d[0], content_new2, flags=re.M)
        p = open(bb, "w+")
        p.write(content_new3)
        p.close()
        os.rename(str(os.path.basename(bb)), g[0] + str(os.path.basename(bb)))
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\local.py", line 74, in <module>
    if e[0] == 'INT':
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 939, in __getitem__
    return self._values[key]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

screen for Excel:

[image]

Below is what the code returns to me. I have listed the most important steps in the code. There is a problem with merging for c for some reason.
The variable dd returns the correct value, the variable df also displays correctly Excel data

```py
print(dd)

       0
0 TABLE3

print(df)
           TYPE_PK TABNAME ...  SCHEMA
0              INT TABLE1       SCHEMA1
1   VARCHAR_DOUBLE TABLE2       SCHEMA1
2          VARCHAR TABLE3       SCHEMA1
3          VARCHAR TABLE4       SCHEMA1


print(c)
Empty DataFrame
Colums: [TYPE_PK, TABNAME, QUERY, QUERY1, SCHEMA, 0]
Index: []
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of your input data.

Comment: For any reason `e = c.loc[:, "TYPE_PK"]` is an empty Series. As you have not shown copyable data, **I** cannot guess why...

Comment: Most likely your merge `c = pd.merge(df, dd, left_on='TABNAME', right_on=0)` is returning zero rows.

Comment: I added more details